# Need to remove duplicate in the following scenario

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table named travel details with have below data

| Source | Destination | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mumbai | Hyderabad | 100 |
| Hyderabad | Mumbai | 100 |

How can I write a query to get only one output when source and destination are vice versa. In the above case I want only one row.

| Source | Destination | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mumbai | Hyderabad | 100 |

I am expecting only one row from above output

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why do you want Mumbai Hyderabad and not Hyderabad Mumbai?

Comment: jarlh is right, imagine 2 places where A -> B is not the same distance than B -> A (it's not uncommon, with one-way streets). Then it makes sense to store in base in different rows. Then when you query the distance, you should know where you start and where you end, and should get only one row. If you want to do otherwise, we need more information: in what use case do you want to query both? Which criteria should be used to de-duplicate them?

Comment: Hi I want any of them.

Comment: I am using MySQL. But did not get why the DBMS is matter as I just want the SQL logic to achieve this

Comment: Because information hovering the sql tag says to add the DBMS. Since query syntaxes and features do vary across DB vendors, and this helps to get an answer relative to the DBMS being used. For example you could get an Oracle SQL that may not work with MySQL or vice versa. (Heck, some queries between MySQL and MariaDB queries may not work with each other depending upon the DB version even though MariaDB forked from MySQL back in 2009 ... but they have become quite divergent since then)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(src, dst), GREATEST(src, dst), distance
```

It puts your src and dst column values in a predictable (lexical) order then removes duplicates.